# iperf3 fast in first second

Tags: tcp, wireguard, iperf3

i have a question to my iperf3 results.

the connection i through a wireguard connection where the server is location in DE and the Client located in IL.

Tests have been conducted from the server (DE)

```
iperf3 -c 10.10.10.2 -p 20003
Connecting to host 10.10.10.2, port 20003
[  5] local 10.10.10.1 port 32840 connected to 10.10.10.2 port 20003
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  8.71 MBytes  73.1 Mbits/sec   46    395 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  6.25 MBytes  52.4 Mbits/sec    0    443 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  5.00 MBytes  41.9 Mbits/sec    3    464 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  3.75 MBytes  31.5 Mbits/sec    3    140 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.25 MBytes  10.5 Mbits/sec    0    203 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec    1    134 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec    0    197 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec    0    252 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  3.75 MBytes  31.5 Mbits/sec    0    296 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  3.75 MBytes  31.5 Mbits/sec    0    338 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  40.0 MBytes  33.5 Mbits/sec   53             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.08  sec  36.2 MBytes  30.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

REVERSE:

```
iperf3 -c 10.10.10.2 -p 20003 -R
Connecting to host 10.10.10.2, port 20003
Reverse mode, remote host 10.10.10.2 is sending
[  5] local 10.10.10.1 port 21844 connected to 10.10.10.2 port 20003
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  13.6 MBytes   114 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  27.1 MBytes   227 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  29.6 MBytes   248 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  29.7 MBytes   249 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  30.4 MBytes   255 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  30.4 MBytes   255 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  30.2 MBytes   254 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  30.8 MBytes   258 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  31.1 MBytes   261 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  31.8 MBytes   267 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.08  sec   292 MBytes   243 Mbits/sec  104             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   285 MBytes   239 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

the connection should be a 300+Mbps in both directions on both connections.

It seems like the client (rpi4) has a good upload to the server of 243 Mbps but a download of only 40Mbps where it seems like that the first second has 73Mbps and then it goes down.

Speedtest on DE Server

```
speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from 1&1 Internet AG (212.227.xxx.xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by FSIT AG (Dietikon) [440.71 km]: 17.857 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 362.51 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 340.56 Mbit/s
```

Speedtest on Client in IL

```
speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Partner Communications (192.116.xxx.xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Partner Communications (Tel Aviv) [244.48 km]: 13.526 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 292.78 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 510.09 Mbit/s
```

Both, Server and Client, are running Debian 11.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Check CPU usage of client and server. Especially if the raspi is plain without heatsink and/or CPU cooler it may overheat quickly and thus throttle itself.

Comment: CPU on both ends look good. RPI has heatsink and fan.